# Getting a TypeError on ackermann function. Not sure why

Tags: python, recursion, typeerror

```py
def ackermann(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return n+1
    if n == 0:
        return (m-1,1)
    else:
        return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))

ackermann(10,5)
```

Getting TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(ackermann(3,4))
  File "main.py", line 9, in ackermann
    return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))
  File "main.py", line 9, in ackermann
    return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))
  File "main.py", line 9, in ackermann
    return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

I tried to visualize this on pythontutor.com and once m is 9, n is returning tuple (9,1) and the error starts.

Comment: `ackermann` sometimes returns a tuple and sometimes returns an int. Then you pass that back into `ackermann` and try and call arithmetic operators on it.

Comment: `return (m-1,1)` returns a tuple. Did you mean `return ackermann(m-1,1)`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes you are right, I forgot to use ackermann(m-1,1).Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When `n` is `0` you return a tuple instead of calling `ackermann`:

```py
def ackermann(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return n+1
    if n == 0:
        return ackermann(m-1,1)
        # Here-^
    else:
        return ackermann(m-1,ackermann(m,n-1))
```

Comment: How do I use timeit function to see how long it takes to run?